# react-native run-android dev mode not working

Tags: react-native

I created the app by working on the following tasks for the launch of the Android app.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
```

After that, I tried to build the app again in development mode (`react-native run-android`), but the app continues to be built in release mode. How do you build it development mode like before?

```
react-native run-android
```

When I do this `react-native run-android`, Metro Bundle does not run and just build the release app on my device.

I want the Metro Bundle to be turned on and built in development mode when I execute this.

Comment: this is only for bundle. react native run android should start the metro server in debug mode itself

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it was fixed by deleting the line:

```
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;
```

from the `MainApplication.java`

Answer (score 0):

Below can clear your thoughts about the metro server and development mode

- When you are in development mode and need to debug the application
  live by changing the content of the code the you should always do:
  `react-native run-android`, it will always run the metro server and
  you have the feature to live reload the application whenever the code
  changes.
   *Note: This will work for both the emulator and phones
  connected to your pc through cables or by server.*
- Now, in case you want to build an apk and wanted to test on a real
  device which enables you to discard the consoles and for the further
  testing the application before making it live then you should always
  run the below command

  1. Bundle first all the files, by going inside your project
     structure
        `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output
     android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
     android/app/src/main/res/`
  2. Now, create a bundle apk by going inside the android folder and run the below command
     `./gradlew assembleDebug`

  Note : it will create the apk in you build folder inside this
  directory
   `project_name\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug`

I hope this helps....Thanks :)

Comment: I'm using react-native run-android but my app crashes on debug mode while it works fine in release mode. It's not connected to bundler and just sttoped. any idea?